# Actual use of the keyword extern

Tags: c

I wrote the following 3 C source files to test the extern keyword
in C :

main.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int var;
int main()
{
   var = 10;
   printf("%d %p",var,&var);
   var = 20;
}
```

main2.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
extern int var;
int main()
{
    printf("%d %p",var,&var);
}
```

other.c

```
int var;
```

I compiled the two files main.c and main2.c separately but also linking
the other.c file with each

On running the first program i got the following output :
10 0x8049660

But on running the second after that i got this :
0 0x8049660

It is evident that the two var's point to the same address which is the
point of using the extern keyword.

But why does it again get initialized to 0 ?

Also if I run the second program without running the first I get 
the same output.

Why is it so ?

Comment: You completely misunderstand what an `extern` declaration does - it is not a means of sharing data between programs.

Comment: The variable is not shared between distinct processes. The address of the variable will be defined during linking, and you can end up with different addresses depending on other global variables that are linked together.

Answer (score 3):

Keyword `extern` is not for sharing variables among different programs or even not among consecutive runs of the same program. A variable declared as `extern` just means that this variable is defined in another translation unit of the same program, and the value of this variable will be shared only in this program run.

Note that `other.c` and `main.c` are two translation units that get linked to the *same* program, let's say `main.exe`. Within one run of `main.exe`, the value of `var` will be shared among `other.c` and `main.c`, and the address will be the same. For a second run of `main.exe`, you may receive different addresses, i.e. a different value for `&var` compared to that of the first run.